# Can i put my personal website link in author meta tag?

Tags: html

I am developing websites for my clients, and i want to leave some credit (Not in visible tags) in meta tags. As of now i am leaving my name in author, recently i created my personal website. Can i leave a link to my personal website in author metatag some thing like below?

```
<meta name="author" content="https://myblog.com">
```

Is there any other better way of giving credits to my website?

Comment: Check out http://humanstxt.org/

Comment: Your contract with your clients should specify how you're allowed to promote or identify yourself on their site. If it doesn't, consult an attorney about modifying that contract. If you don't have a contract, contact your clients and ask them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you have to use a name according to the [W3C Standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#author) for `name='author'`

If you need to add hidden credits for your content, the better way is to use [html](/questions/tagged/html) comments. Because if you use meta tags for your credits there is problem with SEO results and clients.

And also if you have proper agreement with clients add your copyright as visible link to footer.

Hope it helps